# How is matter density derived from CMB?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

As the question says. I am looking for a technical but brief overview of how $\Omega_m$ can be derived from the CMB data to high accuracy for example as in the Planck papers.

Comment: Last time I searched for this I found nothing brief. The only text book I know of which presents the complete derivation is "Physical foundations of Cosmology" by V. Mukhanov. The chapter on CMB is presented on almost 50 pages and I have too admit that I capitulated when trying too read it (I was at the end of my bachelor studies at that point)...

Comment: Hi Photon. My field of study does not include the vocabulary I found in https://www.cosmos.esa.int/documents/387566/387653/Planck_2018_results_L06.pdf . Your question seems to be related to Section 6: Internal consistency of ΛCDM model parameters. Here is a quote: "We first discuss how parameters vary between high and low multipoles, and the relevant features in the power spectra that may be responsible for these shifts." I recommend you make an effort to understand multipoles.  I have no idea how this concept relates to cosmology.